# How to directly land on a non-master branch at github.com when I click on my repo

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I've hosted a [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github)  [project](https://github.com/aurotripathy/ssd-spacenet/tree/ssd). The actual work I did is on the `ssd` branch (not `master`).

When I land on my [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github) site via https://github.com/ and click on my repo `ssd-spacenet`, I get the `master` branch by default. What I want is [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github) to point to my work branch (in this case, the `ssd` branch) and not the `master` branch when I click on the repo link.

Right now, I have to go to the branch button (top and right) and select the `ssd` branch as the master branch shows up by default.

Is there some setting for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project settings in the `Branches` menu you can select the default `branch` that you want. After updating, when you do to your project page, the selected branch will be selected.